# MYSQl - Check if group of dates are in a comma separated list of dates

Tags: mysql, find-in-set

**My table design:**

[image]

How to get the records If **dates** '04-11-2016' OR '11-11-2016' available in `week_days` column.

> Note: The dates are not same, It's have one or more dates.

**Actual Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `sh_products` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('04-11-2016','11-11-2016',week_days);
```

**Expecting Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just OR together two calls to `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT *
FROM sh_products
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('04-11-2016', week_days) > 0 OR
      FIND_IN_SET('11-11-2016', week_days) > 0
```